# Poner en producción un sitio con arquitectura MVC

Tags: php, mvc, .htaccess

Muy buenas tardes, dias, noches para todos. Quisiera aprovechar este espacio para hacer una consulta, espero me puedan ayudar. Creé un proyecto con arquitectura MVC, en mi servidor local "localhost" que uso con WAMP o XAMPP. La cuestión es que quiero ponerlo en producción, pero por alguna razón no me muestra nada solo la pantalla en blanco. Creo que podrá ser alguna configuración de mi .htaccess?

Aclaro, tengo usando 3 archivos .htaccess, obviamente no al mismo nivel. La ruta de mi sitio seria la siguiente: `http://localhost/public/index.php`

El nivel de carpetas que tengo es el siguiente y la configuración para cada .htaccess (Los pongo en orden de como estan en la imagen):

primer .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /public/ [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

.htaccess dentro de app

```
Options -Indexes
```

.htaccess dentro de public

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /public/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Recalco que no tengo mucho conocimiento de .htaccess, les agradezco mucho su ayuda, gracias.

Comment: por lo que comentas entinedo estas utilizando un framework en php, una de las cosas que siempre debes revisar es el archivo de logs

Comment: porque tienes 3 archivos?

Comment: Digamos que como tal un framework no estoy usando tipo (laravel, codigniter, etc), creé las estructura yo mismo, por lo que no tendría un archivo logs, si tal vez hubiese alguna forma de verlo, yo pensaba que podría ser algo del htaccess?

Comment: Siempre tienes un archivo de logs generalmente en Linux es /var/log/httpd/access_log y  /var/log/httpd/error_log, es posible que en esos archivos encuentres algo mas de informacion, de igual forma MAMP o XAMP tienen esos archivos

Comment: Cada archivo tiene una configuración para cada directorio en específico. Recalco que no tengo mucha experiencia con el tema de htaccess. Por ejemplo el segundo archivo hace que no estén visibles las carpetas a través de la URL del directorio /app/ por ejemplo

Comment: Para lo que pretendes hacer sólo necesitas el .htaccess en public (**imagino que ese es el directorio público en el host**) y las reglas en .htaccess deben redirigir las solicitudes a index.php. Adicionalmente, en index.php se invoca al enrutador para que resuelva las direcciones y elija el controlador a cargo. **¿Corresponde public con el directorio público en el host?** Si no es así: edita tu pregunta indicando la posición del mismo, es posible que los problemas se originen allí.

Answer (score 1):

Amigos les agradezco mucho su atención, después de tanto revisar mi código encontré algo muy particular. La vista Admin si me la carga correctamente, así que me puse a ver por qué no me cargaba la principal, y es porque en localhost con WAMP y XAMPP no están configurados como case sensitive mientras que mi sevidor público sí. Entonces al llamar mi controlador `main.php` no lo encontraba así que encontré dos opciones:

1. Cambiar los nombres de mis controladores por CapitalCase
2. La mejor opcion es agregar un parámetro [NC] a mi archivo .htaccess que fue la que usé y me funcionó:

   ```
   RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
   ```